# PrimeNG table header misaligned with scrollbar when adding rows dynamically

Tags: angular, scrollbar, primeng

I have used p-table in angular to display data and used scrollbar with fixed height as `"300px"`

```
<p-table [columns]="myCols" [value]="myList" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="300px" [responsive]="true">
```

Here, I am adding rows to the table dynamically which creates scrollbar at runtime and at that time the header becomes misaligned.

[image]

So it only has scrollbar on body.

If it has scrollbar at page load then it works fine but has issue when we have scrollbar at runtime.

Here is the [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/p-table-primeng-v6-xzzrtp) for the same issue (click 'clone' button to add rows to table dynamically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed it.

Just needed to make use of spread operator `(...)`

Need to add below line at the end of the clone event.

```
this.cars = [...this.cars];
```

Updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/p-table-primeng-v6-kaoym4)

Answer (score 1):

just add margin to align header and body.

```
.ui-table-scrollable-header-box {
   margin-right: 17px !important;
}
```

see this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/p-table-primeng-v6-wyraup).fore more reference visit this [link](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/5354)

Comment: It will be misaligned on load.. I don't want any in-line CSS..

Comment: This works perfect in my case where I always show the scrollbar. Because if I don't then table does not recalculate scrollbar place when changing screen size or list size

Comment: Actually, better to use padding-right.. because sometimes primeng adds padding-right of 17px.. which would add to the margin and cause problems..

Comment: For Mac users, where the scrollbar can be hidden by default until scrolling begins, the `margin-right` and and always showing scrollbar approaches don't quite work

Answer (score 1):

```
::ng-deep .p-datatable-scrollable-header-box {
  margin-right: 17px !important;
}
```

Add these lines on scss file of your compoenent

Answer (score 0):

I have the same trouble as you but i used [resizableColumns]="true". when the header becomes misaligned I will drag the horizontal bar scroll. It will not be misaligned

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's a bug from primeng end, when scrollable height is added to p-table tag and more no.of rows are there then this issue occurs.
When only one row then this issue is not there.

SOLUTION:
Instead of using scrollable and scroll height, add height to the parent tav of the table. With the below mentioned approach I am able to resolve alignment issues.

Eg:`

```
<div style ="max-height:60vh;overflow:auto">
<p-table></p-table>
</div>
```

`